# Status of the discovery of non-abelian anyons and topological quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-computer, software, topological-phase, anyons

This week Microsoft announced that it will make available the programming language for quantum computer available by the end of this (2017) year. https://news.microsoft.com/features/new-microsoft-breakthroughs-general-purpose-quantum-computing-moves-closer-reality/

It is not secret that Microsoft is commited to topological quantum computation with anyons but as anyone can read in wiki then anyons have not been detected up to now and there is only hint of detection in one 2013 article.

What is the status of anyon discovery and manipulation? Are there ideas for succesfull experiments that are not attacked and what are the obstacles? I guess resources are not obstacles for Microsoft.

From the one side Google gives only cited 2013 result and some oldest papers. But from he other side - there should be discoveries if Microsoft is making bold steps for opening quantum computation facilities available.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily infer that plans to release a programming language imply anything about the practicality of a quantum computer. QCL's been available for download for ages, for example. Also note that quantum computers can be to some extent simulated on conventional ones. That aside, I guess your anyon question holds.

Comment: Link http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/qcl.html

Comment: And more business oriened effort http://rigetti.com/ - Rigetti Forest API

Comment: 1. 'Prospects' sounds _primary opinion-based._ 2. Actual physics qs should preferably not be mixed with res. recom. qs.

Comment: This may be summary https://physics.aps.org/articles/pdf/10.1103/Physics.10.68